# Drawing App - Curve Fitting

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, curve-fitting

I'm currently working on a web-based drawing app, where I use the position of the pointer to generate a line. The speed determines the width of the line.

My problem is that the browser events does not produce clean data when getting the position, so the width becomes quite "jittery" other then being soft and smooth.

I'm wondering what is the best way to smooth out that sort of data as the drawing is being made? I was thinking on curve fitting, but I'm not sure which algorithm could work better in my case.

P.S. I'm not redrawing the line from start every single time on canvas, I'm only adding the "final part".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might try pulling both the "smooth" and "simplify" functions out of paper.js (their MIT license allows this).  It worked well for me in an edge detection project. Check it out here: http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/smoothing-simplifying-flattening.